# Куча была повреждена в релиз версии

Tags: c++, файлы

Здравствуйте. Такая проблема возникла, решил собрать для теста релиз версию. И 5-6 из 10 раз при выполнении этого кода (чтение из файла) происходит краш:Куча была повреждена (параметры: 0x776D4270).
При отладке ошибка указывает на эти строки.

```
HANIM::HANIM(char *_name)
{
    wight=0;
    height=0;
    numframes=0;
    name=_name;
    f=fopen(name, "rb");

    if (f == NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
        fread( &numframes, sizeof(int),1 , f );//кадры
        fread( &wight, sizeof(int),1 , f );//ширина
        fread( &height, sizeof(int),1 , f );//высота
```

Ошибка возникает на команде fread. Что можно сделать?

```
 class HANIM
{
public:
    HANIM(char *name);
    ~HANIM();

    char *name;
    //HTEXTURE tex[100];//больше не используется
    int wight;
    int height;
    int numframes;
protected:
    FILE *f;
};
```

Программа 1 создает файл и записывает туда информацию
Сначала в файл записываем начальную информацию

```
fwrite(&frames,sizeof(int),1,f);
fwrite(&wight,sizeof(int),1,f);
fwrite(&height,sizeof(int),1,f);
```

Далее следом записываем запакованный через zlib пакет данных

```
 for( unsigned int i=0;i<destLen;i++)
      {
          fwrite(&packt[i],sizeof(int),1,f);
      };
```

Потом, другая программа последовательно, в том же порядке извлекает информацию.

Весь код загрузчика файлов

```
#ifndef DSANIM_H
#define DSANIM_H

#include <hge.h>-графический двиг
#include <hgesprite.h>-графический двиг
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "zlib.h"
extern HGE *hge;

using namespace std;

class HANIM
{
public:
    HANIM(char *name);
    ~HANIM();

    char *name;
    int wight;
    int height;
    int numframes;

    vector<HTEXTURE> tex;//созданные текстуры

protected:
        FILE *f;
        DWORD *val;
        DWORD tz;
        DWORD a;
        DWORD red;
        DWORD green;
        DWORD blue;
        int loadmode;

        DWORD testmass;

        unsigned long destLen;
        unsigned long compLen;

};

#endif


#include "dsanim.h"


HANIM::HANIM(char *_name)
{
    loadmode=2;
    wight=0;
    height=0;
    numframes=0;
    name=_name;
    f=fopen(name, "rb");

    if (f == NULL)
    {
        hge->System_Log("Файл повреждён :%s", name);
        exit(1);
    }

        int y=0;
        fread( &numframes, sizeof(int),1 , f );//кадры
        fread( &wight, sizeof(int),1 , f );//ширина
        fread( &height, sizeof(int),1 , f );//высота

        /*for(int i=1;i<numframes;i++)
        {
            tex[i] = hge->Texture_Create(wight,height);
        };*/

        if(loadmode==1)
        {//не используется
        };


            if(loadmode==2)//сжатые файлы
            {
                unsigned long ff;
                ff=0;
                unsigned long d1;
                unsigned long d2;
                fread(&d1, sizeof(unsigned long), 1, f);//несжат
                fread(&d2, sizeof(unsigned long), 1, f);//сжат
                unsigned char *newmass=new  unsigned char[d2];//несжат
                unsigned char *newmassu=new  unsigned char[d1];//сжат


                for( unsigned int i=0;i<d2;i++)
                  {
                       fread( &newmass[i], sizeof(int),1 , f );//сжатые данные
                  };

                if (Z_OK == uncompress(newmassu, &d1, newmass, d2))
                {

                    for (int fr = 0; fr < numframes; fr++)
                    {
                        tex.push_back(hge->Texture_Create(wight, height));

                        hgeU32 *pixels = hge->Texture_Lock(tex.at(fr), false);
                        for (int i = 0; i < (wight*height); i++)
                        {
                            pixels[i] = ARGB(newmassu[ff + 3], newmassu[ff + 2], newmassu[ff + 1], newmassu[ff]);
                            ff = ff + 4;
                        };
                        hge->Texture_Unlock(tex.at(fr));

                    };
                };
                  newmass=0;
                  newmassu=0;
            };
        fclose(f);







};
HANIM::~HANIM()
{

};
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40928/discussion-on-question-by-mikhail------).